# How do i get only one value from a parameter using x:bind

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, xbind

I am binding using x:bind which sends parameters as objects to the destination page. I want to retrieve just one value from the parameters. I am sending DetailItems as the parameter. how do i send just one item lets say firstName in DetailItems?

```
 public void MediaPage() =>
     NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MediaPage), DetailItems);
```

see the codes this one is from the viewModel and i am using template10

```
 List<Details> _detail;
    public List<Details> DetailItems { get { return _detail; } set { Set(ref _detail, value); } }

 public class Details : BindableBase
{
    string _Title = default(string);
    public string Title { get { return _Title; } set { Set(ref _Title, value); } }

    string _Image = default(string);
    public string Image { get { return _Image; } set { Set(ref _Image, value); } }

    string _Link = default(string);
    public string Link { get { return _Link; } set { Set(ref _Link, value); } }

    string _background = default(string);
    public string Background { get { return _background; } set { Set(ref _background, value); } }

    string _leftInfo = default(string);
    public string LeftInfo { get { return _leftInfo; } set { Set(ref _leftInfo, value); } }

    string _rightInfo = default(string);
    public string RightInfo { get { return _rightInfo; } set { Set(ref _rightInfo, value); } }

    string _description = default(string);
    public string Description { get { return _description; } set { Set(ref _description, value); } }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work ->DetailItems.firstname?. Your question is not clear. Please post xaml.When are you navigating to another page?

Comment: For some reason i could not access the properties even when i set everything to public.

Comment: Please post your definition of `DetailItems`. Is it a local field/property? The naming indicates that DetailItems is a collection/list (because it's plural). Maybe DetailItems[someIndex].FirstName works?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I have solved the problem using delegateCommand. Very useful with buttons. thanks for your effort